# Center vertically ConstraintLayout with expandable textViews inside ScrollView (scroll/center problem)

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, centering

I created simple layout with 5 expandable textviews inside ConstraintLayout. All it must be scrollable (because there will be a lot of content) so all this is inside ScrollView. All this textViews i want center vertically (should look like on first picture) so I used `android:layout_gravity="center"` to my Constrait. First of all I noticed that when I use `android:fillViewport="true"` on ScrollView then center doesn't work. Otherwise when I use `android:fillViewport="false"` center work but when TextView contains a lot of content it doesn't scroll properly. On second picture you can see that my 1-3 textview just hide (screen is scrolled max to top), on next picture we can see that scrollView doesn't fit properly to content and there is a lot of empty space (that space should be on top where are my missing 1-3 textViews). Why's that ? How to work this out ?

Here some code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/NavigateTopInfo"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MapButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_map"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ExitButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/myLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:context=".InfoActivity">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/squaretextview"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="toggleView"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="TextView1"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1_idcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorepipsum"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/squaretextview"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="toggleView"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="TextView2"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1_idcontent" />




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2_idcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorepipsum"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview2" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/squaretextview"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="toggleView"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="TextView3"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview2_idcontent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3_idcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorepipsum"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview3_id" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/squaretextview"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="toggleView"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
               android:text="TextView 4"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview3_idcontent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview4_idcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorepipsum"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview4" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/squaretextview"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="toggleView"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="TextView5"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview4_idcontent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5_idcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorepipsum"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you considered setting left&right constraints to parent instead of layout gravity?

Comment: but it will center horizontally each textView not vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `ConstraintLayout`. It is responsible for **2nd** and **3rd** problem. To make the view vertically centered place your `ScrollView` inside `RelativeLayout` and set `centerInParent` to true. Besides this to make the view horizontally centered inside `ConstraintLayout` use **left** and **right** Constraint to `parent` and keeps **width** as `wrap_content`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/NavigateTopInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Header content -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    android:text="TextView1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1_idcontent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView1 Content"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    android:text="TextView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1_idcontent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2_idcontent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView1 Content"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview2" />

                <!--Other content -->

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I made this changes and textViews won't center vertically (

Comment: Ok, your answer almost work but. Now all it's centered and scroll well but part of my scrollView goes on my "NavigateTopInfo" RelativeLayout.

Comment: Place my `RelativeLayout` below your `NavigateTopInfo`

Comment: figured it out seconds before you comment :) thanks for help !